# How can I fix the black parts after I apply subsurf?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image: image of face I tried to make, where you can see black pieces]

As you can see in this picture I was trying to create a face, but when I apply a subsurfaces modifier you get these black spots. Does anybody know how to fix this.
thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you possibly upload a picture that is higher res?

Comment: is this better?

Comment: I had a similar issue and my normals were also all outside. Turned out, my sub-div was after edge split. Moving it above solved it. So probably check your modifier stack

Answer (score 2):

It might be because the vertices in the mesh are not made properly positioned that the blender is not able to properly calculate how to apply the modifier. So try these:

1. Recalculate the normals properly using: "Shift+N"
2. Go to edit mode and remove duplicate vertices by "Merge by distance
   option" (make sure you set the proper distance in the dropdown menu). Also, make sure 
   that there aren't overlapping faces